# Most secure method of authentication for an API user?

Tags: rest-api, api, oauth2, apexrest

We have a need for an external site to call services exposed from our Salesforce org via APEX REST. In previous projects I would leverage a connected app with username/password flow and create an API user to authenticate as. They would call OAuth endpoint providing grant_type of "password" and client_id, client_secret, username, and password.

With this new integration I am looking for something more secure. Is there a better OAuth flow to use other than username/password flow? I still want to create an API user to authenticate as, but wondering if there's a better way to authenticate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your use case. You can use JWT if you don't use a browser environment, or the Web Server Flow for a server experience, or the User Client Flow for mobile or desktop apps.